# lmer: 3-way interaction to explore if categorical variable moderates treatment effect

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, interpretation

I evaluated the effectiveness of an intervention by using lme4 package:

```
lmer(Depression ~ time * group + (1|id))
```

resulting in a significant interaction (time * group).

Group: 1 = intervention, 2 = control (reference)
time: 1 = pre-intervention (reference), 2 = post-intervention

In a second step, I explored if a diagnosis (yes/no) has an effect on treatment effectiveness by checking a 3-way interaction with lmer:

```
lmer(Depression ~ time * group * diagnosis + (1 | id))
```

The interaction was not significant. However, the 2-way interaction was no longer significant, the diagnosis itself is not significant. I am not sure about the interpretation: The interaction of group*time is not related to diagnosis?

Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. If you're satisfied by Noah's answer, please accept it by clicking the little *check icon* on the left of his answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The 2-way interaction coefficient for `time` and `group` in the 3-way interaction model does not correspond to a test of whether the 2-way interaction is present, but that is how you are interpreting it. It corresponds to whether a 2-way interaction is present *in the reference group of the third variable*. The fact that it is nonsigificant could mean that there is no 2-way interaction in this subgroup or that the subgroup is too small to be able to detect that interaction, whereas in the larger full sample, the 2-way interaction is detectable. There is no contradiction here.

Remember that a nonsigificant coefficient doesn't mean that coefficient is equal to zero; it can also mean you did not have enough power to detect the nonzero coefficient.

Based on these results, I would conclude that there is not enough evidence to claim diagnosis moderates the treatment effect, but there is evidence of a treatment effect.

Comment: For the 3-way interaction I used 

lmer(Depression ~ diagnosis * group * time + (1 | id))

 I learned that the order of the variables matters. 

I defined ref. cat. as follows: diagnose = 2; group = 2; time = 1

In the R output, the following parameters are given: diagnose(1); group(1); time(2); diagnose(1)*group(1); diagnose(1)*time(2); group(1)*time(2);diagnose(1)*group(1)*time(2)

The 3-way interaction is not significant meaning that Depression does not differ in the two groups at the two timepoints in different diagnosis. Is this correct?

Comment: As per above, the fact that the 2-way interaction of time * group is no longer sign. in this 3-way interaction model corresponds to whether group * time interaction is present in the reference group of the third variable (diagnose 2). 
Isn't the correct interpretation: it corresponds whether group * time interaction is present in the third variable diagnose (2) compared to the reference category of the third variable diagnose (1)?
I'm interested whether there is a 2-way interaction of time * group in the third variable diagnose(1) instead of the presence in the reference group diagnose(2).